# Error Builder in the Imagenetwork does not handle an error if the user enters the screen to load the image and then he left before the image is loaded

Tags: flutter, image, http, flutter-futurebuilder

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: authProvider.getProfileData(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Center(
          child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
              color: Colors.black, radius: 1.4.h),
        );
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return const Center(
          child: Text(' An Error occurred'),
        );
      } else {
        return SafeArea(
          child: ScrollConfiguration(
            behavior: MyBehavior(),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  ProfileAndCoverImageBuilder(authProvider: authProvider),],),)

class ProfileAndCoverImageBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
final Authentication authProvider;
const ProfileAndCoverImageBuilder({required this.authProvider, Key? key})
  : super(key: key);

@override
State<ProfileAndCoverImageBuilder> createState() =>
  _ProfileAndCoverImageBuilderState();
 }

class _ProfileAndCoverImageBuilderState
extends State<ProfileAndCoverImageBuilder> {

 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
  children: <Widget>[
    AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 3 / 2.5,
      child: Container(
        child: Image.network(
          widget.authProvider.coverImageUrl!,
          errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception,
              StackTrace? stackTrace) {
            print("onError B");
            return const Center(child: Text("Error"));
          },
        ),
        
  ],
);
```

}
}

when the user wait the image to load and an error occurred the error will be print perfect without any exception but when the user try to leave the screen before the image is loaded the error will not be handled and an exception will be thrown **HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404,** so how to handle the error also if the user left the screen before the image is loaded

Comment: could you add your full code of this class?

Comment: Sorry, already tried but failed on it